# Regex match in PHP not work as expected

Tags: php, regex

i want to match a title from imdb sites. i test online the pattern regex http://regex101.com. its match and return the title but in PHP no result, no error. what's wrong by the way?

```
<?php
    $imdb = file_get_contents('http://www.imdb.com/title/tt4600952/?ref_=nv_sr_1');

    $sourcecode = htmlentities($imdb);

    preg_match('/<h1 itemprop="name" class="">([a-zA-Z0-9\:\'\ ]+)/', $sourcecode, $title);

    var_dump($title);
?>
```

Comment: Remove the `$sourcecode = htmlentities($imdb);` line as it encodes some special chars.

Comment: if so it now return wrong match.

Comment: That is quite expected, do not use regex to parse HTML.

Comment: `/<h1 itemprop="name" class="">([a-zA-Z0-9\:\'\\\ ]+)/` your missing 2 \\ backslashes it takes 3 backslashes ( 1 for PECL, 1 for PHP and the original) to do a backslash.  regx101.com doesn't account for this issue.  Not sure if it will make a difference though.